# Trying to create python program, but simplified with def

Tags: python, function, simplify

I'm trying to create a program without importing anything. The program lets the user input a passage, then prints how many A's there are in the message, how many B's, etc. 
So it works...it's just VERY long. I'm new to coding, and I know that there is a way to simplify the code below with def but I'm not really sure how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Arrays, arrays, arrays....

Comment: @jason, just out of curiosity are you interested in displaying every letter of the alphabet, even if it's not in the input? I.e. all the letters that are 0?

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't matter too much, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need no methods, but you can definately cut it short:

- String can be used as an **array of characters**.
- You can use the `index` method to determine what is the **position of the letter** in the alphabet.
- You can iterate a **zipped list** of pairs from the **alphabet and the counter** list, to produce the output.
- Use `if letter in alphabet` as a guard to ensure the letter is valid for the alphabet, instead of hard coding the alphabet. That way you can even **expand your alphabet**. (Note that the counter is set to the length of the alphabet).

Here is a suggestion:

```
message = input('what is your message? ').upper()
alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
counter = [0] * len(alphabet)

for letter in message:
    if letter in alphabet:
        counter[alphabet.index(letter)] += 1

for letter, count in zip(alphabet, counter):
    print(letter, ':', count)
```

Comment: You can also change the alphabet string to have a space at the end, and the c list to have 27 elements. Just so that a string with spaces can be processed

Comment: @creeperdomain see whatI wrote about ensuring letter is valid and expanding alphabet.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Is there a substitute for zip() and for line 7 in the code you suggested?

Comment: line 7 is simply incrementing the cell value by one, very common practice.

Comment: instead of zipping, you can iterate `alphabet` and print the letter, and the counter for the index of the letter (`counter[alphabet.index(letter)]`) like in the first loop. but zip is easier

Comment: for i in message:
    print (i,"...",count[alphabet.index(i)])

Comment: ^ this works, kinda, but I think I put the count in the wrong place (my variables are different, sorry -i is letter, counter is count) because it prints out how many letters are in the message, but it repeats itself.

Comment: Not sure how to fix it :/ thank you so much, though.

Answer (score 0):

One can do it with a one line instruction, where we make use of:

- `count` method of string that returns the numbers of element contained in a string
- `chr` function that gives a character from an `int`. `chr(65)` gives a `A`, `chr(66)` gives a `B`, ...
- `join` function that concatenates strings of a list

The result looks like

```
message = input('what is your message? ').upper()
print('\n'.join([chr(65+i)+':'+str(message.count(chr(65+i))) for i in range(26)]))
```

Comment: OP didnt stated he was in a code-golf competition ,but how to use readable style for shortening his code. also, iterating all the list by count every time is a waste, and a polinomial complexity instead of linear.

Comment: I admit this is not really easy to understand, however it introduces new concepts that a new programmer may be interested in. Moreover iterating over thé whole alphabet is interesting for messages with more than 26 characters!

Comment: Actually, using this code will generate problems for custom charsets. It works only for the range of a-z, and if you want spaces or another characters they wouldn't be included. That's why it's better comparing each char with the charset and learning *it's* position, rather than hard coding charsets.

Answer (score 0):

For a very short and elegant solution use the Counter unit from the collections module:

```
from collections import Counter

message=raw_input("what is your message?")
message=message.upper()

c = Counter(message)
print c.most_common()
```

This counts every kind of letter in the message. And it can even sort the result for you quickly. Here is a sample dialog:

"what is your message?Hi there, new Pythonist!

[(' ', 3), ('E', 3), ('H', 3), ('T', 3), ('I', 2), ('N', 2), ('!', 1), (',', 1), ('O', 1), ('P', 1), ('S', 1), ('R', 1), ('W', 1), ('Y', 1)]"